# org-element--cache-sync is needlessly called with setting initial-major-mode to org

Tags: org-mode

In my case mu4e compose mode, everytime I got the error below:

> Error running timer `org-element--cache-sync': (wrong-type-argument hash-table-p nil)

This simptom is already subscribed as bug, but unresolved.
https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/emacs-orgmode/2015-08/msg00947.html

It seems that `(setq initial-major-mode 'org-mode)` makes this happen.
Are there any good way to get rid of this timer error?

Comment: What version of `org-mode` does this happen with, and have you tried a `grep` for `org-element--cache-sync` within the `.../org` source directory to locate where the timer is being set?  If so, consider updating your question with a citation to the offending code.